# How to get the instance of currently selected li using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I need to get the instance of current selected li, which is dynamically generated, I am using below code :

using $(this) is not giving the instance of current selected li. Please see code details below :

//Add classes on selection of a message

```
$("ul").on("click", "li", function () { AttachEvents(); });

        function AttachEvents() {
            parentID = $(this).('li label[id="discussionID"]').val();
        };
```

below is the HTML code :

```
   <ul id="ui-discussion">
        <li class="ui-discussion-parentmessage ui-state-active">
            <div>
                <div id="empImage">
                    <img src="Images/emp1.png"></div>
                <div>
                    <label id="empName">
                        Gareth Sweet</label><label id="chatdate">24 Jul 2013</label><label>Loremipsumdolorsitamet,
                            consecteturadipisicingelit,seddoeiusmodtemporincididuntutlaboreetdoloremagnaaliqua.Ut</label><label
                                id="discussionID">983402</label></div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <ul>
            <li class="ui-discussion-childmessage">
                <div>
                    <div id="empImage">
                        <img src="Images/emp2.png"></div>
                    <div>
                        <label id="empName">
                            Vincent Cash</label><label id="chatdate">24 Jul 2013</label><label>Loremipsumdolorsitamet,consecteturadipisicingelit</label></div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li class="ui-discussion-childmessage">
                <div>
                    <div id="empImage">
                        <img src="Images/emp3.png"></div>
                    <div>
                        <label id="empName">
                            Tucker Montgomery</label><label id="chatdate">24 Jul 2013</label><label>Loremipsumdolorsitamet,consecteturadipisicingelseddoeiusmod</label></div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <li class="ui-discussion-parentmessage ui-state-active">
            <div>
                <div id="empImage">
                    <img src="Images/emp1.png"></div>
                <div>
                    <label id="empName">
                        Gareth Sweet</label><label id="chatdate">9/18/2013</label><label>Hi</label><label
                            id="discussionID">590079</label></div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="ui-discussion-parentmessage ui-state-active">
            <div>
                <div id="empImage">
                    <img src="Images/emp1.png"></div>
                <div>
                    <label id="empName">
                        Gareth Sweet</label><label id="chatdate">9/18/2013</label><label>This is a test message</label><label
                            id="discussionID">424769</label></div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="ui-discussion-parentmessage ui-state-active">
            <div>
                <div id="empImage">
                    <img src="Images/emp1.png"></div>
                <div>
                    <label id="empName">
                        Gareth Sweet</label><label id="chatdate">9/18/2013</label><label>New Message</label><label
                            id="discussionID">255351</label></div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="ui-discussion-parentmessage ui-state-active">
            <div>
                <div id="empImage">
                    <img src="Images/emp1.png"></div>
                <div>
                    <label id="empName">
                        Gareth Sweet</label><label id="chatdate">9/18/2013</label><label>Hi</label><label
                            id="discussionID">2030</label></div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="ui-discussion-parentmessage ui-state-active">
            <div>
                <div id="empImage">
                    <img src="Images/emp1.png"></div>
                <div>
                    <label id="empName">
                        Gareth Sweet</label><label id="chatdate">9/18/2013</label><label>hi hi hi</label><label
                            id="discussionID">154860</label></div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <ul>
            <li class="ui-discussion-childmessage">
                <div>
                    <div id="empImage">
                        <img src="Images/emp1.png"></div>
                    <div>
                        <label id="empName">
                            Arti Agarwal</label><label id="chatdate">9/18/2013</label><label></label></div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li class="ui-discussion-childmessage">
                <div>
                    <div id="empImage">
                        <img src="Images/emp1.png"></div>
                    <div>
                        <label id="empName">
                            Arti Agarwal</label><label id="chatdate">9/18/2013</label><label></label></div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <li class="ui-discussion-parentmessage ui-state-active">
            <div>
                <div id="empImage">
                    <img src="Images/emp1.png"></div>
                <div>
                    <label id="empName">
                        Gareth Sweet</label><label id="chatdate">9/18/2013</label><label>hi</label><label
                            id="discussionID">282729</label></div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <ul>
            <li class="ui-discussion-childmessage">
                <div>
                    <div id="empImage">
                        <img src="Images/emp1.png"></div>
                    <div>
                        <label id="empName">
                            Arti Agarwal</label><label id="chatdate">9/18/2013</label><label>hi</label></div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <li class="ui-discussion-parentmessage ui-state-active">
            <div>
                <div id="empImage">
                    <img src="Images/emp1.png"></div>
                <div>
                    <label id="empName">
                        Gareth Sweet</label><label id="chatdate">9/18/2013</label><label>hi</label><label
                            id="discussionID">587583</label></div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="ui-discussion-parentmessage ui-state-active">
            <div>
                <div id="empImage">
                    <img src="Images/emp1.png"></div>
                <div>
                    <label id="empName">
                        Gareth Sweet</label><label id="chatdate">9/18/2013</label><label>HI</label><label
                            id="discussionID">395700</label></div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Your code is filled with syntax errors, and won't work at all ?

Comment: "As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live()."

Comment: `id` if an element must be unique... use class instead... you have multiple elements with ids `empImage`, `discussionID`, `chatdate` etc

Comment: There could be errors b'cos I have written only few lines over here. I will edit the question & try to make it error free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a working sample:  http://jsbin.com/eTUxAzU/1/
instead of live use jquery on.

```
parentID = $(this).find('li label[id="discussionID"]').val();
does not have val() method.

instead u should use 
parentID = $(e.target).parent().closest('li').find('label[id="discussionID"]').text();
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` inside the event handler refers to the `li`

```
$(this).addClass('ui-state-active');
```

update:

```
$("ul").on("click", "li", AttachEvents );

    function AttachEvents() {
        parentID = $(this).find('label[id="discussionID"]').val();
    };
```

Comment: No problem, just a sidenote really? Your answer wont help much when the next line says `$(this).('li label[id="discussionID"]')`

Comment: i have edited code, It was just a code snippet from hundreds of lines. I need find the instance of current selected li. $(this) is not helping.

Comment: No, Its not working. If i execute $(this) in console it gives me - [Window]. It is not taking instance of selected li at all.

Comment: @user2614405 sorry, it should have been `$("ul").on("click", "li", AttachEvents );`

Answer (score 0):

> $(this) is not giving the instance of current selected li

Try to use `event` parameter instead `this` to access to current element, like this:

```
<ul class="target" >
            <li>Pear</li>
            <li>Apple</li>
            <li>Plum</li>
        </ul>

$(".target li").live( "click", function(event){
console.log(event.currentTarget);
});
```

Console output should be like this:

```
<li>Pear</li>
```

Comment: Since $(this) is giving [Window] event.currentTarget is giving #document. :(